# Prove that $f:M(m \times n,F) \to Hom(F^n,F^m)$ is an isomorphism of vector spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

So, I'm trying to prove the following result:

The map $f:M(m \times n,F) \to Hom(F^n,F^m)$, which associates a linear map from $F^n$ to $F^m$ to a matrix from the set of $m \times n$ matrices with entries from a field F is an isomorphism of vector spaces.

---

Proof Attempt:

Now, we just have to prove that it is linear and that it is bijective. Let $A_1,A_2 \in M(m \times n,F)$. Then:

$f(A_1+A_2) = L_0:F^n \to F^m$

We have used the fact that every matrix has a linear map associated with it. In fact, the above means that $f$ is additively linear. So:

$f(A_1+A_2) = f(A_1)+f(A_2)$

Similarly, let $A \in M(m \times n, F)$ and $\lambda \in F$. Then:

$f(\lambda A) = L_1 : F^n \to F^m$

Since $L_1$ is a linear map, it follows that:

$f(\lambda A) = \lambda \cdot f(A)$

We, now, have to prove bijectivity. First, we prove that it is injective. Let $A_1,A_2 \in M(m \times n, F)$ such that:

$f(A_1) = f(A_2)$.

Now, this is going to be a linear map between $F^n$ and $F^m$. From a previously proven result, it is clear that every linear map has a unique matrix associated with it such that $x \to Ax$ for every $x \in F^n$. Hence:

$A_1 = A_2$

To prove surjectivity, we need to show that $f(M(m \times n, F)) = Hom(F^n,F^m)$. Let $L \in Hom(F^n,F^m)$. Since every linear map has a unique matrix associated with it, it suffices to say that there exists an $A \in M(m \times n, F)$ such that $f(A) = L$. However, that means that $L \in f(M(m \times n, F))$. This proves that $Hom(F^n,F^m) \subset f(M(m \times n,F))$ and, thus, establishes equality of the two sets.

That proves the desired result.

^Does my argument above work or no? What could I fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined $f$. Hints:

$(1).\ $ Let $A=(a_{ij})_{1\le i\le n;\ 1\le j\le m}$ and choose bases $\{e_i\}_{1\le i\le n}$ and $\{e'_i\}_{1\le i\le m}$ for $F^n$ and $F^m$ respectively.

$(2).\ f$ will send $A$ to a $\textit{function}\  \phi: F^n\to F^m.$ So, to define $f$, you need to say how $\phi$ acts.

$(3).\ $But the action of $\phi$ is specified by defining it on the basis $\{e_i\}_{1\le i\le n}$ and extending by linearity (this way, you force $\phi$ to be linear), which means that $\phi$ is determined by $(\alpha_{ij})_{1\le i\le n;\ 1\le j\le m}$ such that $\phi(e_i)=\sum^m_{j=1} \alpha_{ij}e_j'.$

$(4).\ $ Make the obvious choice for the $\alpha_{ij}$, and $\textit{now}$ check that $f$ is linear.

Comment: Hmm alright, I'll see if I can make something work with that. Hmm, but the rest of my proof that deals with the bijectivity of the function is fine, right?

Comment: I think you $have$ to define $f$ as in my answer. That is, $f$ is uniquely determined. Your proof seems to assume what you want to prove (e.g. linearity), unless I am missing something. The point is, you need to send a matrix to a $linear$ function $\phi$ so to determine $f$ you have to say what  $\phi$ is.

Comment: Hmm alright, let me try banging my head against this once more. It's just really annoying that I'm not able to get this completely right.